# how to fill with 0 in pandas dataframe with fixed index number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I want use CNN for some data table (dataframe or ndarray)
but I have different row data in each index.

Source :

```
mIndex  valueA  valueB
------  ------  --------  
  1       111     10      
  1       112     20      
  2       222     30      
  2       221     40      
  2       223     50      
  3       333     60
```

Hope : (max 3 rows each index)

```
mIndex  valueA  valueB
------  ------  --------  
  1       111     10      
  1       112     20   
  1         0      0
  2       222     30      
  2       221     40      
  2       223     50      
  3       333     60    
  3         0      0
  3         0      0
```

I want to do this for the CNN pedding.

But Is it possible to do this in numpy or keras pedding function?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

First apply `np.array` to get arrays, then apply `pd.Series` to basically pivot the values of each columns to a row so we can use stack to convert.
After that we use `stack` and keep the `NaN`.

In the end we `concat` all the dataframes to one final dataframe over `axis=1`

```
cols = ['valueA', 'valueB']
dfs = []
for col in cols:
    dfs.append(df.groupby('mIndex')[col].apply(np.array)
                                        .apply(pd.Series)
                                        .stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=0)
                                                            .rename({0:col}, axis=1))

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_final)
   mIndex  valueA  mIndex  valueB
0       1   111.0       1    10.0
1       1   112.0       1    20.0
2       1     NaN       1     NaN
3       2   222.0       2    30.0
4       2   221.0       2    40.0
5       2   223.0       2    50.0
6       3   333.0       3    60.0
7       3     NaN       3     NaN
8       3     NaN       3     NaN
```

## Method 2

we can be accesing the `groupby` elements

```
df= pd.concat([
       d.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(range(3))
       for n, d in df.groupby('mIndex')
], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
   mIndex  valueA  valueB
0     1.0   111.0    10.0
1     1.0   112.0    20.0
2     NaN     NaN     NaN
3     2.0   222.0    30.0
4     2.0   221.0    40.0
5     2.0   223.0    50.0
6     3.0   333.0    60.0
7     NaN     NaN     NaN
8     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only do it in a dumb way, maybe someone has a better solution:

```
# df
   mIndex valueA valueB
0       1      a      a
1       2      b      b
2       2      b      b
3       3      c      c
```

Here we go:

```
# get number of required padding
nPad = df.groupby('mIndex').mIndex.count().transform(lambda x: 3-x)

# get paddings
pads = []
for i, row in nPad.items():
    for _ in range(row):
        pads.append([i, 0, 0])
pads = pd.DataFrame(pads, columns=df.columns)

# padding
df = pd.concat([df, pads], ignore_index=True)
       .set_index('mIndex').sort_values('mIndex')
```

After padding:

```
   mIndex valueA valueB
1      a      a
1      0      0
1      0      0
2      b      b
2      b      b
2      0      0
3      c      c
3      0      0
3      0      0
```

Comment: @Erfan What is wrong? Order? You can use `groupby` again.

Comment: add `df = pd.concat([df, pads], ignore_index=True).sort_values('mIndex')`